# Automatic LHS reallocation with overloaded assignment

Tags: fortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

I have a code, which segfaults with all compilers I have at hand, when doing an assignment to an unallocted allocatable on the LHS with a structure constructor on the RHS. The structure (derived type) itself has an overloaded assignment. I thought, that automatic reallocation of the LHS should occur before the assignment routine is called, but it does not seem to be the case.

Below the code, demonstrating the issue. Uncommenting the allocate statement makes everything working, but I do not understand, why the explicit allocation is necessary in this case. Funny enough, if I remove the overloaded assignment, things work as well.

Any hints?

```
module dummy
  implicit none

  type :: DummyType
    integer :: ii
  contains
    procedure :: assignDummyType
    generic :: assignment(=) => assignDummyType
  end type DummyType

  interface DummyType
    module procedure DummyType_init
  end interface DummyType

contains

  function DummyType_init(initValue) result(this)
    integer, intent(in) :: initValue
    type(DummyType) :: this
    this%ii = initValue
  end function DummyType_init

  subroutine assignDummyType(this, other)
    class(DummyType), intent(out) :: this
    type(DummyType), intent(in) :: other
    this%ii = other%ii + 1
  end subroutine assignDummyType
end module dummy

program test_dummy
  use dummy
  implicit none

  type(DummyType), allocatable :: aa

  !allocate(aa)   ! Should be covered via automatic reallocation...
  aa = DummyType(42)

end program test_dummy
```

Comment: Haven't looked at the code, but what versions of what compilers do you have? Some were a bit late to include automatic reallocation.

Comment: The most recent ones from GNU, Intel and NAG. But apparently, it seems to be an issue with the standard, not with the compilers, as explained by IanH below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [recent discussion on comp.lang.fortran](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.fortran/Vk4D8iDZOdc/discussion) dealing with this topic.

An assignment statement is either an intrinsic assignment or a defined assignment.  Intrinsic assignment permits [re]allocation of the left hand side, defined assignment does not.

When you provide a procedure for the assignment generic identifier, your assignment is defined assignment.  The characteristics of the argument that corresponds to the left hand side then require that the left hand side be allocated.

Comment: Would be nice if you could add a link.

Comment: @IanH Oh, I understand, thanks! This then means, if one uses a type provided by a library, one must have some knowledge about the actual realization of that type (whether the assignment has been overridden or not) if one wishes to assign it to an allocatable without explicit allocation. I do not find it intuitive... 
I'd also appreciate, if you could provide the link to the discussion on comp.lang.fortran.

Comment: Then for the sake of users of your library, consider wrapping types that require defined assignment in another type that is exposed to clients.